# Print all bibliography entries except "dataonly" ones

Tags: biblatex, biber

As part of a literature survey, I have produced an enormous BibTeX file (in Biber dialect) that contains entries (including abstracts) for all the literature of interest.  I made liberal use of `crossref` fields to avoid time-consuming and error-prone repetition of proceedings/book titles, publisher addresses, etc.  Those crossreferenced entries that are not of interest to me (except as a source of data) I have marked with `dataonly = {true}`.

Without manually specifying the keys, how can I print my entire bibliography except for the `dataonly = {true}` entries?

Here is a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{abstract}{\par\small#1}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\printfield{abstract}\finentry}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@proceedings{acl,
  publisher = {Association for Computational Linguistics},
  address = {Stroudsburg, PA},
  dataonly = {true},
}

@proceedings{acl2015,
  year = 2015,
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 53rd Meeting of the ACL},
  crossref = {acl},
  dataonly = {true},
}

@book{wordnet,
  year = 2016,
  booktitle = {An Introduction to WordNet},
  editor = {Gary Gnu},
  crossref = {acl},
  dataonly = {true},
}

@inproceedings{foo,
  author = {Foo Bar},
  title = {Some article},
  abstract = {Here is the abstract.},
  crossref = {acl2015},
}

@incollection{quux,
  author = {Quux quuux},
  title = {Why I love {WordNet}},
  abstract = {Another fine abstract.},
  crossref = {wordnet},
}

% And hundreds more entries...
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This prints the following:

[image: A bibliography showing five entries, including the dataonly = {true} ones]

However, what I want to display is the following:

[image: A bibliography showing only the two entries not marked as dataonly = {true}]

Comment: Unable to run your code. @Psychonaut

Comment: @BikiTeron The code should run flawlessly with a current version of both `biblatex` and Biber.

Comment: can we run on Texmaker? @Psychonaut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are halfway there, it's not `dataonly = {true}`, it's

```
 options = {dataonly=true},
```